# Prove that any other vector $u \in U$ such that $T(u)=v$ can be expressed as $u= \hat v+n, \ \ n \in \text{range}(T).$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:U \to V$ be a linear transformation and fix a vector $v \in \text{range}(T)$. Let $ \hat v \in U$ be some other fixed vector such that $T(\hat v)=v.$

Prove that any other vector $u \in U$ such that $T(u)=v$ can be expressed as

$$u= \hat v+n, \ \ n \in \text{null}(T).$$

**Answer:**

Since $T$ is linear

$U=\text{null}(T) \oplus \text{range}(T)$.

Would it help me?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense: you can't always add $\hat v$ and $n$ if $n\in V$ and $\hat v\in U$. Should it be $n\in\ker(T)$?

Comment: @Dave, yes it was my mistake, $ n \in \text{null}(T)$.

Comment: What if U is infinite dimension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set $n:=u-\hat v$ then use linearity to show that $n\in\ker(T)$, and you get $u=\hat v+n$ for free.